# I want to convert base64 to blob in Objective-c

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, base64, blob

This is JavaScript code which convert base64 to blob.

but I want to make this kind of code in objective-c.

I can't search in stack overflow.

```
function base64_to_blob(base64String) {
   var byteString = window.atob(base64String);
   var array = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
   for (var i = 0; I < byteString.length; I++) {
      array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   var blob = new Blob([array], {
      type: ‘image / jpeg’,
      name: “image.jpg”
   });
   return blob;
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: First of all why can't you search in stack overflow ? Second, clarify what you exactly want ? What you have tried yet ?

Comment: Tim   I think  you trying to covert base64 string to  nsdata(blob) format .

Comment: Is nsdata matching to blob type?

Answer (score 0):

Time use this code my be helpful for you if.

```
-(NSData *) base64_to_blob(base64String) {
   NSData * blobData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString: base64String options:1];
    return blobData;    
}
```